# How remove \n from lines

Tags: parsing, go, line

```golang
file, _ := os.Open("x.txt")
f := bufio.NewReader(file)

for {
    read_line, _ := ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print(read_line)

    // other code what work with parsed line...
}
```

End it add `\n` on every line , end program to work , only work with last line...

Please put example, I try anything end any solution what i find here not work for me.

Comment: Please spend some time at the [help] to understand how to ask here. Not with cross tagging for example.

Comment: It doesn't add the newline, the newline is there in the file. From [the documentation on ReadString](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString), "ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to and including the delimiter." It does *exactly what it says* it will do.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can slice off the last character:

```
read_line = read_line[:len(read_line)-1]
```

Perhaps a better approach is to use the strings library:

```
read_line = strings.TrimSuffix(read_line, "\n")
```

Comment: Not work :( read_line[:len(read_line) - 1] evaluated but not used

Comment: You have to use the result: read_line = read_line[:len(read_line)+1]

Comment: .warpwallet2.go:72: undefined: strings in strings.TrimSuffix

what import need add for it start work ? find sorry a try add string need been add stings :/

Comment: Try `import "strings"` :-)

Comment: `read_line[:len(read_line)-1]` can strip last character if the file has no newline at the end of file. Should use TrimSuffix.

Comment: idk why but ```TrimSuffix``` or ```TrimRight``` did not work in my case. I had to use ```TrimSpace```.

Answer (score 25):

If you want to read a file line-by-line, using [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) will be easier. Scanner won't includes `endline` (`\n` or `\r\n`) into the line.

```
file, err := os.Open("yourfile.txt")
if err != nil {
    //handle error
    return
}
defer file.Close()

s := bufio.NewScanner(file)
for s.Scan() {
    read_line := s.Text()

    // other code what work with parsed line...
}
```

If you want to remove `endline`, I suggest you to use [`TrimRightFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRightFunc), i.e.

```
read_line = strings.TrimRightFunc(read_line, func(c rune) bool {
    //In windows newline is \r\n
    return c == '\r' || c == '\n'
})
```

**Update:**
As pointed by @GwynethLlewelyn, using `TrimRight` will be simpler (cleaner), i.e.

```
 read_line = strings.TrimRight(read_line, "\r\n")
```

Internally, `TrimRight` function call `TrimRightFunc`, and will remove the character if it match any character given as the second argument of `TrimRight`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more easy just with `read_line = strings.TrimRight(read_line, "\r\n")`?

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn you're correct. I misunderstood the `TrimRight` function. I thought it will remove the strings if it *exactly* match the second argument.

Comment: Ah, I just asked that because I'm a newbie Gopher and sometimes there are excellent reasons for doing things in a non-obvious-way. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 19):

## Clean and Simple Approach

You can also use the `strings.TrimSpace()` function which will also remove any extra trailing or leading characters like the ones of regex `\n`, `\r` and this approach is much more cleaner.

```
read_line = strings.TrimSpace(read_line)
```

Go doc: https://pkg.go.dev/strings#TrimSpace

Comment: This comment was perfect !