# how to remove trailing "\r\n" from string

Tags: string, go

I tried with the following code but getting the same string in result:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var s = "\b\x02\b\x02\r\n"
    a := fmt.Sprintf("%q", s)
    fmt.Println("a:", a)
    b := strings.TrimRight(a, "\r\n")
    fmt.Println("b:", b)
}
```

Comment: [possible duplicate question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448384/how-remove-n-from-lines-from-golang)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`strings.TrimRight()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#TrimRight) works just fine. The "problem" in your case is that the `string` value stored in the `a` variable **does not end** with `"\r\n"`.

The reason for that is because you "quote" it using [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf), and the string will end with `"\\r\\n"`, and additionally even a double quotation mark will be added to it (that is, it ends with a backslash, the letter `r`, another backslash, the letter `n` and a double quote character).

If you don't quote your string, then:

```
var s = "\b\x02\b\x02\r\n"
fmt.Printf("s: %q\n", s)
b := strings.TrimRight(s, "\r\n")
fmt.Printf("b: %q\n", b)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mflUfqVJs8R)):

```
s: "\b\x02\b\x02\r\n"
b: "\b\x02\b\x02"
```

Comment: Just a small note, using `%q` it actually ends with `\r\n"` because it also wraps the input string in quote characters.